# How do I install GNU Readline?

Tags: 12.04, gnu, readline

Basically as per question. I have the `.tar.gz` file but I can't seem to install it. I did the whole, `./configure`, `make` and `make install` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not install the package?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can install the packages by using the command in a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to bring it).

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev
```

The package `libreadline` is for running applications using `readline` command

and the package `libreadline-dev` is for compiling and building `readline` application.

[Credit goes to this blog post](http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/install-readline-linux/)

Comment: In debian 10 the `readline` command cannot be found after installing `libreadline7` and `libreadline-dev`. Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: currently on Ubuntu, it is `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev`

Answer (score 17):

`libreadline6` don't work anymore.

The latest one is `lib32readline7`.

Or it's better to look at the available libraries along with a short description using following code:

> `apt-cache search readline`

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get install lib32readline7 lib32readline-dev
```

can be used.

Comment: this wokred on buster-slim but not on bullseye

Answer (score 6):

at the date of writing (2023) readline is now at the version 8:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline8
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

note that there is no more version in the name of the developper package libreadline-dev

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 22LTS below should work

```
sudo apt-get install lib32readline8 lib32readline-dev
```